# Can I "archive" older responses to a surveymonkey survey?

Tags: surveymonkey

We have a survey that we cannot access via the API.  Can I archive older responses, and continue to collect more responses on this same survey?

"Survey requested 'XXXXXXXX' has 728960 respondents, maximum allowed is 500000"

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'archive' responses, only delete them.  If you do this, then you will be able to access the survey via the API, however I can't really recommend this as there is no way to get that data back or to re-enter it if you export it first.

If you don't mind the analyze tab not showing previous responses, your best bet is to copy your survey and then use the new one to collect responses.  We realize this isn't ideal - eventually we'd like to have an asynchronous API so we can support surveys of any length.